# Linked list printing blank

Tags: java

My linked list is printing blank. Can someone explain what I am missing here.

```
class Linklist {
private Linklist first;
public int items;
public int itemLocation;
public int lastIndex = -1;
private final String[] list;
public Linklist nextlink;

//Link constructor
public Linklist(int totalItems) {
    items = 0;
    list = new String[totalItems];
}

public Linklist getNext()
{
    return this.nextlink;
}

public void setNext(Linklist n)
{
    nextlink = n;
}

public void insert (String item){
    list[items] = item;
        items++;
}

public void delete(String item){
    int location = 0;

    while(item.compareTo(list[location]) != 0)
        location++;

    list[location] = list[items -1];
    items--;
}

public boolean doesExist (String item){
    boolean search;
    int location = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    search = (location < items);
    while (search && !found)
    {
        if (item.compareTo(list[location])==0)
            found = true;
        else
        {
        location++;
        search = (location<items);
        }
    }
    return found;
}

public void printUnsortedlist(){
    System.out.print("{" + list + "} ");
}

public void printList(){
    Linklist currentLink = first;
    System.out.print("List: ");
    while(currentLink != null){
        currentLink.printUnsortedlist();
        currentLink = currentLink.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}

public class Unsortedlist{
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Linklist list = new Linklist(9);

    list.insert("Sun");
    list.insert("Mercury");
    list.insert("Venus");
    list.insert("Earth");
    list.insert("Mars");
    list.insert("Jupiter");
    list.insert("Neptune");
    list.insert("Saturn");
    list.insert("Uranus");


    list.printList();

    list.delete("Sun");

    if(list.doesExist("Earth"))
        System.out.println("Earth is in the list");
    else
        System.out.println("Earth does not exist!");

    list.printList();

}
}
```

This is my output:

```
List: 
Earth is in the list
List: 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

When I integrate a `size()` method for example:

```
 public int size(){
 int currentSize = 0;
 Linklist current = head;
 while(current != null){
    currentSize = currentSize + 1;
    current = current.getNext();
}

    return currentSize;
}
```

I get this as the output:

```
{8} Earth is in the list
```

My linked list is there but can not figure out why it is printing blank.

Comment: `printList` starts at `first`.  Look for all the places where you set `first` in your class, and make sure it's being set to the right value.

Answer (score 0):

For your code ,a few places make me more confused.

First,Why you already have a field "list" ,but then you also set a pointer to the nextlink,if you just want to print as a list ,you could only set two field `String value` and `Linklist next`,then you can print your list .

Second,I think the reason why your list is blank is that you set `first` to `currentLink` ,and first is null all the time.To solve this problem ,maybe you can change `first` to `this`,then your `while` code will run as you like it.

Just like this:

```
public void printList(){
    Linklist currentLink = this;
    System.out.print("List: ");
    while(currentLink != null){
        currentLink.printUnsortedlist();
        currentLink = currentLink.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

But still ,you need to improve your code at many places is you really want the code do a perfect job.Hope this help you out.